# And statement using grep/regular expressions

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I'm using grep to search for text within a specific directory. I would like to return rows of text that contain stringA AND stringB.

I know that doing **grep "stringA|stringB"** is effectively an OR statement, is there something I can do, maybe using regex, that would allow me to run an AND statement ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't know the order of the items, you could always reverse a pattern using |

```
grep '1st pattern.*2nd pattern|2nd pattern.*1st pattern' foofile
```

This works geat with two items, three or more would start slowing things down for sure...

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe through two greps:

```
 ... | grep "stringA" | grep "stringB"
```

Note that if your patterns are actually fixed strings and not regular expressions then you can use [`fgrep`](http://ss64.com/bash/fgrep.html) instead of `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

```
"stringA.*stringB"
```

This will locate stringA with any number of any characters between stringB at last